# C# dictionary initializer compilation inconsistency

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, syntax, dictionary, initializer

The following code compiles, but fails with a `NullReferenceException`:

```
class Test
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Dictionary { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var x = new Test
    {
        Dictionary =   // fails
        {
            { "key", "value" }, { "key2", "value2" }
        }
    };
}
```

If you replace the line marked 'fails' with the following, it works (as expected):

```
Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
```

Is there any purpose to the failing syntax--can it be used successfully in some other case? Or is this an oversight in the compiler?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No, it's not a mistake... it's a flaw in your understanding of initialization syntax :)

The idea of the

```
Dictionary = { ... }
```

is for cases where the caller has *read* access to a collection property, but not *write* access. In other words, situations like this:

```
class Test
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> dictionary 
        = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public Dictionary<string, string> Dictionary { get { return dictionary; } }
}
```

Basically it ends up being calls to Add, but without creating a new collection first. So this code:

```
Test test = new Test { Dictionary = { { "a", "b"}, {"c", "d" } };
```

is equivalent to:

```
Test tmp = new Test();
Dictionary<string, string> tmpDictionary = tmp.Dictionary;
tmpDictionary.Add("a", "b");
tmpDictionary.Add("c", "d");
Test test = tmp;
```

A good example of where this is useful is with the `Controls` collection for a UI. You can do this:

```
Form form = new Form
{
    Controls = 
    {
        new Button { Text = "Hi" }, 
        new TextBox { Text = "There" } 
    }
};
```

but you couldn't actually *set* the `Controls` property, because it's read-only.

Comment: So it's used to add items to a dictionary created by the constructor--I should have realized that. But it's an odd use of the equals operator, since the effect is to add to whatever's already in the dictionary (the constructor may have added items first).

Comment: Sort of, yes... but at the same time it's used to set the initial values in the collection, so it fits in in that way.

Comment: Right. The missing `new` should have been a red flag .. but having never used this syntax, I took the equals operator too literally.

Answer (score 4):

You can still use the syntax you want in a constructor:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"a", "b"},
                {"c", "d"}
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

It fails with a null reference exception because you have declared a variable (Dictionary) that is unintialised, hence it is null.

When you attempt to add the entries into it using the initialiser syntax, you are trying to write data into a null object.

When you replace the line with a "= new Dictionary...", you are creating a new object for Dictionary to reference, and hence you are then able to add entries into it successfully.

(In Jon Skeet's example, the Controls collection must already have been created by the Form, hence it works ok)

Comment: Fair enough. Jon answered your question so I thought I'd fill in the reason in case you didn't understand the failure.